# Maxscript variable operators and comments

Tags: variables, comments, operators, maxscript

I've just discovered a small oversight in Maxscript. This is a rhetorical question: You can have `i -=1` in Maxscript, but why can't you have `i--` or `--i`?

Is there anyway around the above example to disable comments or does this force the user to use the former example to increment a variable by -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment with the former or `x = x -1`.
It is a scripting language that is awfully rigid when it wants to be.
Convention of the double dash and the double plus do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Because `--` means the beginning of a single-line comment.

Comment: Your eye needs to be drawn to the word "rhetorical".